# how to get list id of newly created list in mailchimp using mailchimp3 python api

Tags: python, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have created a list in mailchimp using python mailchimp3 api:

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp
client = MailChimp(mc_api='', mc_user='')
data = {
        "name": string*,
        "contact": object*
        {
            "company": string*,
            "address1": string*,
            "city": string*,
            "state": string*,
            "zip": string*,
            "country": string*
        },
        "permission_reminder": string*,
        "campaign_defaults": object*
        {
            "from_name": string*,
            "from_email": string*,
            "subject": string*,
            "language": string*
        },
        "email_type_option": boolean
    }
client.lists.create(data=data)
```

Now after creating this list, how would I get the list id of this newly created list? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally.

```
 list = client.lists.create(data=data)
 list_id = list['id']
```